# Theos "make" error: class method not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, theos

I'm trying to make a tweak with Theos for iOS 8. Its appointment consists in closing app switcher when the last application was closed (when only SpringBoard card remains). Here is the full source code (please don't pay attention on UIKit/UIKit.h, I know that there also must be <>):

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h


@interface SBAppSwitcherIconController {

NSMutableArray *_appList;

}

@end


@interface SBAppSwitcherController

- (void)_quitAppWithDisplayItem:(id)arg1;

//custom method
- (void)_dismissAppSwitcher;

@end


@interface SBUIController

+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (void)dismissSwitcherAnimated:(_Bool)arg1;

@end


%hook SBAppSwitcherController

- (void)_quitAppWithDisplayItem:(id)arg1 {

    %orig();

    if ([[%c(SBAppSwitcherIconController) _appList] count] == 0) {

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(_dismissAppSwitcher) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

}

%new


- (void)_dismissAppSwitcher {

    [[%c(SBUIController) sharedInstance] dismissSwitcherAnimated:YES];

}


%end
```

When I try to compile it with "make package install" command, I get this error:

```
Tweak.xm:38:65: error: class method '+_appList' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]
    if ([[_logos_static_class_lookup$SBAppSwitcherIconController() _appList] count] == 0) {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SBAppSwitcherIconController does not have the class method '_appList'. You can view the header here:
https://github.com/coolstar/iOS-8.1-SpringBoard-Headers/blob/master/SBAppSwitcherIconController.h

A class method will have a '+' in front of the function header. For example, SBAppSwitcherIconController has two class methods(which won't be helpful for your tweak however):

+(float)nominalDistanceBetween5IconCentersForSize:(CGSize)size;

+(float)nominalDistanceBetween3IconCentersForSize:(CGSize)size;

Comment: Ok, so, can you please tell me, how to get SBAppSwitcherIconController's _appList from SBAppSwitcherController's -(void)_quitAppWithDisplayItem...?